# What is the Inverse of $n$ in this algorithm for FFT over rings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, fast-fourier-transform

On this algorithm, the last step involves $n^{-1}$, but I'm in doubt about the inverse of $n$ in what ring? It surely isn't talking about $1/n$ as these are operations on a ring of integers.

[image]

Comment: $1/n$ is really just a scalar scale factor.

Comment: @Hilmar but with some rounding? When it does $mod q$ does it do some rounding? Because it can't be just plain $1/n$

Comment: It could be the inverse of $n$ modulo $q$. For example $2$ has inverse $3$ modulo $q=5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It surely isn't talking about 1/ as these are operations on a ring of integers.

> but with some rounding? When it does  does it do some rounding? Because it can't be just plain 1/

It looks to me like it is operations in $\mathbb Z/q\mathbb Z$, which is a field as $q$ has been assumed to be prime.  Since $n$ is a power of $2$ it is certainly nonzero in $\mathbb Z/q\mathbb Z$, and therefore it has an inverse in that ring.

There is no rounding or anything involved.  The inverse is perfectly well defined $\pmod q$.